# Can I specify a git branch when using cabal2nix?

Tags: nix

When using `cabal2nix` I can download from Github like so:

```
cabal2nix https://github.com/MaxGabriel/u2f > u2f.nix
```

Is there a way to also specify a branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't, but, if you feel like improving it, this looks like a [starting point](https://github.com/NixOS/cabal2nix/blob/1109639366c36ca42b074291622d1903847102dc/src/Distribution/Nixpkgs/Fetch.hs#L112).